# Package options mtplusscr and mtpluscal don't work in MTPro2 complete

Tags: fonts, packages, package-options, mtpro

If I use them I don't get the MTMS and MTMSB fonts as described in the guide just the old times new roman. Anyone seen this before?

**EDIT:** Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage[mtplusscr]{mtpro2}    
\begin{document}        
$$ \mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} $$   
\end{document}
```

And in the log file (which is way too long to reproduce here) it says that:

```
No file Umtms.fd. on input line 5. LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/mtms/m/n' undefined.
```

Comment: I can confirm that this problem also occurs on my system (MacTeX2011, MacOS X 10.7.2): when loading the `mtpro2` package with either the `mtplusscr` or `mtpluscal` options, I get Computer Modern, and not TNR as you note, when executing the commands `\mathscr{ABC}` and `\mathcal{ABC}`.

Comment: Make a small complete example, compile it with pdflatex and then show the example and the log-file.

Comment: I added a minimal example with the relevant part of the log file in the post.

Comment: @Mico --- does my answer fix the problem on your machine?

Comment: @IanThompson -- Thanks for contacting me. I'm afraid I only have the `mtpro2` package, but not the `mtpro` or `mtpb` packages. Hence I can't run your MWE.

Comment: @Mico --- The free version doesn't include the other two. If you have MTPro2 complete you should have them, though.

Comment: @IanThompson: I'm afraid that neither `mtpro`, `mtprob`, nor `mtpb` are on my system. Likewise, there's no `mtprob.map` file. To get the free subset of the `mtpro2` package, one must specify `\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}`. However, the Times-compatible `script`, `curly`, `fraktur` and `blackboard-bold` fonts only come with the "complete" version of `mtpro2`.

Comment: @Mico --- My mistake; version 1 of `mtpro` came with two additional packages `mtpb` and `mtpams` and had three map files. Looks like version 2 has only one of each, so my suggestions are no good!

Comment: @IanThompson -- thanks so much for trying to help. I have a feeling (but don't have the time to follow up on this hunch with the maintainers of the `mtpro[2]` package) that the `mtplusscr` option is deprecated but that this fact hasn't made it to the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of MTPro2 (my version is 2.3) states that the options `mtpluscal` and `mtplusscr` "assign the MTMS and MTMSB script fonts, which were part of Y&Y’s MathTıme Plus collection, to `\mathcal` and `\matbcal`", and `\mathscr` and `\mathscrb`, respectively. I read that as these fonts are not part of MTPro2, but are just made bound to these commands if you happen to have the older MathTime Plus collection.